# Linux copy file and rename to substring of filename

Tags: linux, bash, shell

My files got this structure:

```
mynewfile-runtime-tested-1102-19.4-alpha.zip
mysdk-sdk-tested-1102-19.4-alpha.zip
sources-tested-1102-19.4-alpha.zip
```

I looking for a way how to dynamically detect and drop the suffix of **tested-1102-19.4-alpha** and to copy the files with new names so it will look like:

```
mynewfile-runtime.zip
mysdk-sdk.zip
sources.zip
```

The suffix should be detected dynamically by delimiters ('-'), my other chunk of file have suffix like **nottested-404-11.2.34-beta** and the other one is **final-01-1-release**. The only thing remain constant is the delimiter of '-'

Comment: Which `-` is the correct one? The first, the second, from the left, or the right? Please give an unambiguous specification.

Comment: You need to count from the right. So the 4th - from the right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for file in *.zip; do
  mv "$file" "${file%-*-*-*-*.zip}.zip"
done
```

This is fully portable POSIX shell, without forks to sed or other programs.
The `${file%pattern}` bit says to remove the **shortest** matching string.

You can also remove the **longest** match with `%%`, or from the **left** with `#` and `##`, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

To only move the files that match the pattern you can do this:

```
#!/bin/sh                                                                       
suffix='-*-*-*-*.zip'                                                           
for file in *$suffix                                                            
do                                                                            
  trimmed=${file%$suffix}                                                       
  echo mv "$file" "$trimmed".zip                                                
done
```

Remove the `echo` when you are confident with the result.

Comment: the suffix is dynamically changing

Comment: so add it as a parameter to the script or use wildcards/regex

Comment: @user2988257: So you want everything after the first dash to be stripped?

Comment: actually the perfix is between 4th dash (-) from the right and until .zip

Comment: @user2988257: Then see the edit. Note that the quotes in the loop are removed.